# Find & replace script for User to alter hyperlinks via Website

Tags: replace

I have a list of hyperlinks on a webpage and I want to allow the user to perform a find and replace command that will alter all the hyperlinks at once and yield a custom list that they can copy and paste elsewhere.

Example:

google.com/search?q=search+phrase&pws=0

google.com/search?tbm=blg&q=search+phrase&pws=0

For above two URLS (pretend they're hyperlinked), a user can perform a find and replace, finding "search+phrase" and replacing it with "custom+search+new" to render the following new hyperlinked URLS:

google.com/search?q=custom+search+new&pws=0

google.com/search?tbm=blg&q=custom+search+new&pws=0

It could be a combination of http://htmlsandbox.com and http://textmechanic.co/Find-and-Replace-Text.html

Comment: Are they in a textfield or are they actual links (`<a href="blah"></a>`)?

Comment: I want them to end up as actual links. I envisioned a text field for the find and replace command that renders the new links in a new html frame, like a combo of htmlsandbox.com and textmechanic.com/Find-and-Replace-Text.html. But I'm open to whichever is easiest (and least load on server).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression and either JavaScript or Jquery.

Since you didn't mark `Javascript` or `JQuery`, here's an example with jQuery (thought it can be easily replaced with `Javascript`).

```
function replaceCustomSearch (custom) {
    var patt = /q=[\w\d\+]+/;
    $('a[href]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            href = $this.attr('href');
        if (patt.test(href)) {
            href = href.replace(patt.exec(href), "q=" + custom);
            $this.attr('href', href);
        }
    });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UP8x5/

Comment: This looks great. Unfortunately I'm too ignorant to know what to do with that code, how to tie it into a user input text field, etc. I'm afraid I need instructions on how to make this operate in a wordpress page. Sorry I'm a newb!

Answer (score 0):

You are not really clear in your question about where this is for. As you are stating that things have to change on the client side (and don't mention anything on the server side), it makes sense to do this with just a client-side programming language. In the browser javascript will be a logical solution. When you are going to do more complex things, you might want to look into a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). For now I'll give both solutions in plain javascript, as this is too simple to load a complete library for.

**Replacing text in a text field**

If you are making something like an editor, you are probably going to find and replace something in a text field.

```
function doReplace() {
  var s = document.getElementById('search').value;
  var r = document.getElementById('replace').value;

  var oldtext = document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML;
  var newtext = oldtext.replace( s, r );

  document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = newtext;
}
```

This uses the [replace-method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on strings. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/bsrgj/) is a fiddle for that.

**Replacing text in actual links**

```
var $a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var search = "asdf";
var replace = "qwer";

for( var i = 0; i < $a.length; i++ ) {
    $a[i].href = $a[i].href.replace( '/' + search + '/g', replace );
}
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PW36b/). It uses a regex and [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: Yes, client side only: I have a list of 20 google search links that I want a client to be able to alter with a single search and replace command. I want the result to be actual hyperlinks that the client can just click on. I also need instruction on where to put this code. Again, sorry I'm a newb.

Comment: I've been more thorough then I would normally have been. On StackOverflow you require at least basic understanding of the problem. If you don't know what JavaScript is, google it. If you don't know how to use JavaScript is, google it. If you are unsure what these snippets of code do, go to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org) and research what a function does, what it takes as arguments and what it returns. This is very straight-forward code.

Comment: Thanks. I have messed with the code in fiddle to get what I want. I'll figure out how to implement it.

Comment: So I'm almost there, and learning a ton. My modified fiddle: jsfiddle.net/H4FYj/   Problem: Search and replace only does the first link, not the second. I want it to do as many links as I have listed. Also, I if a user inputs a phrase, I want the replace tool to automatically replace the space between words with a "+" in the URL. Possible?